# Need assistance to install npm require-in-the-middle in Ubuntu

Tags: npm

```
User@userAcc-Dummy:/$ sudo apt-get install npm require-in-the-middle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package require-in-the-middle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require-in-the-midlle` is a hook to be installed by `npm`:

```
sudo apt install npm
npm install require-in-the-middle --save
```

Source: https://npm.io/package/require-in-the-middle

Comment: I have already installed the npm version (6.14.4+ds-1ubuntu2). However, when I am trying to install a pluging {node scripts/generate_plugin --name test -y}  ; I am getting an error mentioned below                      internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'require-in-the-middle'

Comment: Great. you can skip that step then. The point here is to understand the hook isn't installed from the Ubuntu repositories and not a .deb. It has to be installed by `npm` and, of course, `npm` has to be installed first (with `apt`). Is there soemthing else you don't understand? If this answer is useful please accept it.

Comment: I understand the theoretical part you mentioned above; but still I don't get my answer :)    How I can install npm or  "require-in-the-middle" from Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: Really? So, recapitulating: 1st you install `npm` (if already installed move on to the hook installation) the 2nd you install the hook with the second command. What exactly are you still not understanding?

Comment: @NiveditaK ChanganAuto clearly states in the answer that you DO NOT install `require-in-the-middle` from the repositories, but that `npm` installs it as a hook instead.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for further clarification; I don't often work with such stuff and when I was running the npm install require-in-the-middle --save cmd it was giving me Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in") . Now I am able to install hook with sudo user using same command